# Adding <!DOCTYPE html> ruins alignment

Tags: css, html

I forgot to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to some projects so I went back and added it. This ruined the alignment/height of a few elements but I was able to fix it by adding in `px` or `%` where it was missing.

However, in one of my projects this didn't fix the problem. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn3z9e6k/2/). It's the button heights which should fill the entire container. It works great without `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I have looked at other similar questions but the advice given (add in missing `px` or `%`) hasn't worked.

Here's the CSS for the buttons:

```
button {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    height: 15% !important;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F8B8B8;
    border: 1px solid #fee;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: Do not use id like classes, id MUST be unique for entire document

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/tn3z9e6k/4/

```
.buttonrow { // created from #buttonrow
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height:calc(400px / 5); // total height / rows
}


button {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F8B8B8;
    border: 1px solid #fee;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! The only issue is that it made the calculator too long, so instead of `height: calc(400px / 5);` I used `height: calc(400px / 6.5);`.

Comment: i use `calc()` only for readability reason, since there was 5 rows of buttons you can use normal value in pixels/em/rem etc.

Answer (score 1):

percentage is work according to the height of the parent container, so you should mention height to the `#buttons` ( buttons container div).

see below css -

```
#buttons {
    height: 75%;
}

#buttonrow {
    height: 20%; /* you have 5 rows, so it will be 20% */
}

#buttons button {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/w3xshybk/3/

The problem is not with the DOCTYPE declaration. You have not set the height of divs properly.

You had set the height of the div with id `calcbox` to 400px.

But the next child div with id `buttons` is not taking the full height of `calcbox`. So, I assigned 100% height to it.

Then I have assigned 20% height to `#buttonrow` so that the 5 rows take 20% each of the total height.

Then I added 100% height to buttons.

(Your mistake: adding 15% height to button will not take 15% of 400px but will take 15% of it's parent i.e. buttonrow . )

https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/w3xshybk/3/